# Syncing photos from iPhoto on a Mac to Photos under iOS8

Tags: photos.app, ios

iTunes used to have an option for syncing an iPhoto library with one's iPhone. This seems to be gone now, leaving only the option of syncing a folder of pictures from one's Mac. Is there some way to sync an iPhoto library, or should I export all these photos to a directory and sync that?

Answer (score 1):

Sync Photos from ... iPhoto [or Aperture, a named folder, or Pictures]

- All photos, albums, Events & Faces

That's everything.

Alternatively,

- Selected albums Events & Faces & automatically include events from...

[image]

Comment: Weird. That option is not appearing for me.